# MySQL Replication : SQL Thread, which privileges?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, replication, privileges

I'm trying to replicate datas from Master to Slave with MySQL.

When activating slave ("start slave" command on MySQL), 2 threads are created :

- I/O Thread
- SQL Thread

The last one reads requests from the relay-log.info file (written by the I/O thread), and executes theses request on the database.

**My question is :**

How does the SQL Thread execute these requests ? Which Mysql user does it use ? What are its privileges ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the slave server, replication is done at low-level, under no special account. The [`SUPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/start-slave.html) privilege is required to run the `START SLAVE` statement.

See the last listing on [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-implementation-details.html). The threads show as belonging to "system user".

The Slave server connects to the Master as the user specified in the [`CHANGE MASTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/change-master-to.html) statement. This user must exist on the Master, and requires the [`REPLICATION SLAVE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/change-master-to.html) privilege.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just saw the "system user", it seems to be a specific user for this application...
Do you think this "system user" has same privileges than the "root" user ?

Comment: I'd rather put it this way: this user has the [`SUPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege (because you can revoke privileges from `root`, just like any other user).

Comment: So with the SUPER privilege, the "system user" can also start and stop the replication ?

Comment: I suppose it *could*, but this isn't a problem, is it? I *hope* replication control statements are not replicated (but I don't have a system to play with at this time).